# Future Builder stuck at ConnectionState.waiting

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So im doing a read on firebase to get data so i can build my profile page. I think right now is showing me only the default and if i add: case ConnectionState.waiting than it only shows the circularProgressIndicator. Here is my code and i dont know if im doing wrong the future builder or the future function getData()

```
class ProfileClient extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileClient({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileClientState createState() => _ProfileClientState();
}

class _ProfileClientState extends State<ProfileClient> {
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String name ;
  String email ;
  String biographie ;
  String nationalite ;
  String genre ;
  String niveau ;
  String specialite ;
  String equipment ;
  String langue ;
  String age ;
  String rs;

  Future getData() async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
        setState(() {
          name = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['name'];
          email = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['email'];
          biographie = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['biographie'];
          nationalite = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['nationality'];
          genre = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['genre'];
          niveau = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['niveau'];
          specialite = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['specialite'];
          equipment = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['equipment'];
          langue = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['langue'];
          age = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['age'];
          rs = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['rs'];
        });
      }else {
        print('Document not found');
        return null;
      }
    }
    );
  }

  TextStyle style1() {
    return TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue.shade900, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900);
  }

  TextStyle style2() {
    return TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.shade900, fontSize: 15);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //MainScreen is just a class that return appbar bottom bar navigation and one background image
    return MainScreen(
      currentIndex: 3,
      isSelectedHome: false,
      isSelectedSecond: false,
      isSelectedFourth: false,
      isSelectedThird: true,
      child: new FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>snapshot) {

            switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Check your internet connection!!')));
              case ConnectionState.active:
              case ConnectionState.done:
                return new ListView(
                  children: [
                    //this is how i show the data
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 30, 25, 10),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white70,
                        child: new Row(
                          children: [
                            new Text(
                              'nom:',
                              style: style1(),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  name,
                                  style: style2(),
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                   
                  ],
                );
              default: return ListView(
                children: [
                  Same ListView...
                ],
              );
            }
          }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: forgot to tell that the default works fine becouse i can see my profile page really nice, but the problem is that in console it happens a loop of my print('document data: ${documentSnapshot.data}'). so it keeps printing me the data non stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because your `getData()` method is getting called each time you used `setState` and this leads the `FutureBuilder` to show you the default state or the loading indicator whenever you add `ConnectionState.waiting`.

This breaks the guide for using `FutureBuilder`.

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
> State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or
> State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the
> State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the
> FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the
> FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt,
> the asynchronous task will be restarted.
>
> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

**Solution:**
Keep a reference to the Future outside your `build` method and define it in your `initState`. And so if you call `setState`, it doesn't trigger the future to fire again.

Your code should be updated to this below:

```dart
    class ProfileClient extends StatefulWidget {
      const ProfileClient({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _ProfileClientState createState() => _ProfileClientState();
    }
    
    class _ProfileClientState extends State<ProfileClient> {
      final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    
      String name ;
      String email ;
      String biographie ;
      String nationalite ;
      String genre ;
      String niveau ;
      String specialite ;
      String equipment ;
      String langue ;
      String age ;
      String rs;
    
      Future getData; //Add this line

   
      //Add this code block
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();

        getData =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
                .get()
                .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
              if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
                setState(() {
                  name = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['name'];
                  email = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['email'];
                  biographie = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['biographie'];
                  nationalite = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['nationality'];
                  genre = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['genre'];
                  niveau = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['niveau'];
                  specialite = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['specialite'];
                  equipment = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['equipment'];
                  langue = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['langue'];
                  age = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['age'];
                  rs = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map)['rs'];
                });
              }else {
                print('Document not found');
                return null;
              }
            }
            );
      }

      TextStyle style1() {
        return TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue.shade900, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900);
      }
    
      TextStyle style2() {
        return TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.shade900, fontSize: 15);
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //MainScreen is just a class that return appbar bottom bar navigation and one background image
        return MainScreen(
          currentIndex: 3,
          isSelectedHome: false,
          isSelectedSecond: false,
          isSelectedFourth: false,
          isSelectedThird: true,
          child: new FutureBuilder(
              future: getData, //Update this line
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>snapshot) {
    
                switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.none:
                    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Check your internet connection!!')));
                  case ConnectionState.active:
                  case ConnectionState.done:
                    return new ListView(
                      children: [
                        //this is how i show the data
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 30, 25, 10),
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            child: new Row(
                              children: [
                                new Text(
                                  'nom:',
                                  style: style1(),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Text(
                                      name,
                                      style: style2(),
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                       
                      ],
                    );
                  default: return ListView(
                    children: [
                      Same ListView...
                    ],
                  );
                }
              }
          )
        );
      }
    }
```